# How do i append this item to the same list, instead of creating a new list everytime it loops?

Tags: python, list, loops, append

this is my current code:

```
fd = open('/var/log/secure.log')
syslog = fd.readlines()

countTable = {} # initialization of a dictionary
for line in syslog:
        data = line.split()  
        if len(data) >= 15:
                if data[14] in ['user=root']:
                        intrusions = []
                        ip = data[13].replace('rhost=', "")
                        intrusions.extend(ip)
                        print "intruder:", intrusions
```

and this is the output i get:

```
intruder: ['218.92.0.201']
intruder: ['222.186.173.142']
intruder: ['222.186.173.142']
intruder: ['222.186.173.142']
intruder: ['218.92.0.201']
intruder: ['218.92.0.201']
intruder: ['222.186.30.218']
intruder: ['218.92.0.201']
```

how can i get all of those IP's into the same "intrusions" list?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to move your `intrusions = []` before the first loop:

```
countTable = {} # initialization of a dictionary

intrusions = []
for line in syslog:
        data = line.split()  
        if len(data) >= 15:
                if data[14] in ['user=root']:

                        ip = data[13].replace('rhost=', "")
                        intrusions.extend(ip)
                        print "intruder:", intrusions
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out this python noob!